# Magento 2.2.10 is it possible to get all the orders status is pending?

Tags: orders, order-status, items, order-items, sales-order-item

I want to get all the orders where the status is pending. 
I want to do a second check where if the item status is cancelled.
Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
$orders->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array(cancelled)));
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$pendingOrdersCollection = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Sales\Model\Order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'pending'));
$canceledOrdersCollection = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Sales\Model\Order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 'canceled'));

?>
```

Hope this will help you!